# Is Bonferroni but not Tukey HSD a method of correction for pairwise comparison?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

What is the relationship between Bonferroni and Tukey HSD, are they just two methods of conducting corrections for post-hoc tests? If this is the case, could I say "post-hoc testing was conducted using Tukey-HSD adjustment/correction"?

Or is it the case that Tukey HSD is a procedure of post-hoc testing and Bonferroni is a correction method? If this is the case, could they combine with each other?

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that the Bonferroni correction can be applied to any set of independent $p$-values whereas the Tukey HSD method only applies to pair wise comparisons between means. Both of them control the family-wise error rate. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) on that subject compares them and offers some advice about ones which you have not considered. Note that if you decide to use Bonferroni there is a better method with the same assumptions due to Holm. This is also sometimes known as the Holm-Bonferroni procedure.